# How to iteratively change nodes position Networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I have this graph:

[image]

I would like to change the position of the nodes by **dragging** them with the **mouse**. If it were possible it would be better to do it from the console
I am using Google colab for this project.

This is my code:

```
nodes = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'])
edges = np.array([['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['C', 'F'], ['C', 'G']])
pos = np.array([[0, 0], [-2, 1], [2, 1], [-3, 2], [-1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 2]])

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

plt.figure(3,figsize=(12,12)) 
pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw(
    G,
    pos=pos,
    node_color='#FF0000',
    with_labels=True
)
```

I tried using:

```
import networkx as nx
import netgraph
I = netgraph.InteractiveGraph(G)
```

But on Google Colab it doesn't work.

How could this be done?

Comment: Google Colab does not support interactive drawing. Links [1](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/616#issuecomment-506829877), [2](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/86), [3](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15161).

Comment: Okok thank you so much

Comment: My pleasure. I am the author of netgraph. Next time that something with my code doesn't work, feel free to raise an issue on github. I am more likely to see it there than randomly stumble across it on SO. ;-)